# Error: Unable to activate Windows Store app …. The xxx.exe process started, but the activation request failed with error ‘The app didn’t start’

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate update 4, I have developed a universal app for the store and the phone under Windows 8.1.  The app is implemented upon the Prism for Windows Runtime.

The app is at its final testing stage.  I have no problem to run/test it with the corresponding emulators and devices (Surface Pro and Lumia 1020) until few days ago. Although the app can still run/test with the emulators (The store app can be still packaged and deployed to Surface Pro for testing). But I will receive following error message when running with device (Lumia 1020) under Visual Studio 2013:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app ….  The xxx.exe process started, but the activation request failed with error ‘The app didn’t start’.

I have tried all followings in number of times, still received the same error message (there is no app.config file used in app (at least not being seen in the solution pane and windows explorer):

1. Roll back to the change set where I have successful made the build and deployed to Phone.
2. Run repair on Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed.

I have used MS Ocr Lib. for Phone once which only works for ARM. After using NuGet to remove Ocr lib., OcrResource folder still remains in the phone project.

To fix the problem, one must either deletes OcrResource folder if the target platform is for Any CPU, or keep OcrResource folder and set the target platform as ARM.